# Funduino Uno -- Error at Upload : avrdude: stk500_getsync() not in sync: resp=0x6e

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I bought a new Funduino uno board 2 days ago and now I cant upload any sketches from my Arduino IDE...

Always I get the error:

```
Programmer not resonding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e
```

I tried :

- Port Change.
- Driver deinstall and new install.
- Reset Button at the board.

Thanks for help!

Have a nice day and greetings On3

Comment: This is not a *programming* problem, try asking at [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://arduino.stackexchange.com) or [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the most probable issue is that your funduino does not make the auto-reset when avrdude uploads the sketch. The second issue is that your funduino does not contain a correct bootloader.

Those kind of trouble shooting are explained [here on arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting).

For boot loader, you will be redirected to this [arduino page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader).

I detail correct timing of reset because this is not very precise on some places. On arduino boards there is a bootloader that eases the uploading of sketch. This is a small piece of program that can listen to serial (through USB) port, and loads the sketch. The bootloader software is executed **only** on startup and has a timeout of about 1s. The arduino IDE must upload the sketch at this moment, otherwise avrdude will complain of "programmer not responding".

For most arduino boards, when you open serial port, this triggers an auto-reset of board, so the bootloader is executed and can receive a new sketch.

You can see messages in your arduino IDE. When you push upload:

- IDE compiles your code.
- IDE open serial port, so that the board auto reset, and starts bootloader.
- IDE (with avrdude tool) sends the sketch to board.

If you dont trust automatic process, you can manually press the reset button at the time the IDE is ready to upload sketch (just after compile).